# HTML Interactive Graphic Wheel

Tags: jquery, html, svg, jquery-animate, css-animations

How do I do an interactive hover over animation like the image below for a site?

I can do a simple css hover and size it if they are flat square images but I am really stumped on how to do this in a wheel shape like the image below.

[image: How do I do something like this?]

Comment: Please post the code of this wheel shape. If possible, make a runnable snippet.

Comment: Hi, I don't have the code for it yet, that's why I am asking. This is just an AI/PSD rendition of what I am trying to do.

Comment: StackOverflow doesn't work this way... We can only help if you already have some code to go on and you're stuck somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

You can take reference of this link

[Wheel menu demo](https://codepen.io/lenymo/pen/rwmBGq) 
    HTML

```
<div class="radial-menu">
  <ul class="radial-menu__menu-list">
    <li class="radial-menu__menu-item">
      <div class="radial-menu__menu-link-bg"></div>
      <div class="radial-menu__menu-icon">
        <span class="oi" data-glyph="bold" title="Bold" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      </div>
      <div class="radial-menu__menu-content">
        <div class="radial-menu__menu-content-wrapper">
          <h6 class="radial-menu__menu-content-title">
            Bold
          </h6>
          <p class="radial-menu__menu-content-description">
            Make text bold
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="radial-menu__menu-link"></a>
    </li>

    <li class="radial-menu__menu-item">
      <div class="radial-menu__menu-link-bg"></div>
      <div class="radial-menu__menu-icon">
        <span class="oi" data-glyph="italic" title="Italic" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      </div>
      <div class="radial-menu__menu-content">
        <div class="radial-menu__menu-content-wrapper">
          <h6 class="radial-menu__menu-content-title">
            Italic
          </h6>
          <p class="radial-menu__menu-content-description">
            Make text italic
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="radial-menu__menu-link"></a>
    </li>

    <li class="radial-menu__menu-item">
      <div class="radial-menu__menu-link-bg"></div>
      <div class="radial-menu__menu-icon">
        <span class="oi" data-glyph="underline" title="Underline" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      </div>
      <div class="radial-menu__menu-content">
        <div class="radial-menu__menu-content-wrapper">
          <h6 class="radial-menu__menu-content-title">
            Underline
          </h6>
          <p class="radial-menu__menu-content-description">
            Underline text
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="radial-menu__menu-link"></a>
    </li>

    <li class="radial-menu__menu-item">
      <div class="radial-menu__menu-link-bg"></div>
      <div class="radial-menu__menu-icon">
        <span class="oi" data-glyph="align-left" title="Align left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      </div>
      <div class="radial-menu__menu-content">
        <div class="radial-menu__menu-content-wrapper">
          <h6 class="radial-menu__menu-content-title">
            Text Alignment
          </h6>
          <p class="radial-menu__menu-content-description">
            Set text alignment
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="radial-menu__menu-link"></a>
    </li>

    <li class="radial-menu__menu-item">
      <div class="radial-menu__menu-link-bg"></div>
      <div class="radial-menu__menu-icon">
        <span class="oi" data-glyph="list-rich" title="Bulleted List" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      </div>
      <div class="radial-menu__menu-content">
        <div class="radial-menu__menu-content-wrapper">
          <h6 class="radial-menu__menu-content-title">
            Bulleted List
          </h6>
          <p class="radial-menu__menu-content-description">
            Add a bulleted list
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="radial-menu__menu-link"></a>
    </li>

    <li class="radial-menu__menu-item">
      <div class="radial-menu__menu-link-bg"></div>
      <div class="radial-menu__menu-icon">
        <span class="oi" data-glyph="list" title="Numbered List" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      </div>
      <div class="radial-menu__menu-content">
        <div class="radial-menu__menu-content-wrapper">
          <h6 class="radial-menu__menu-content-title">
            Numbered List
          </h6>
          <p class="radial-menu__menu-content-description">
            Add a numbered list
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="radial-menu__menu-link"></a>
    </li>

    <li class="radial-menu__menu-item">
      <div class="radial-menu__menu-link-bg"></div>
      <div class="radial-menu__menu-icon">
        <span class="oi" data-glyph="header" title="Heading" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      </div>
      <div class="radial-menu__menu-content">
        <div class="radial-menu__menu-content-wrapper">
          <h6 class="radial-menu__menu-content-title">
            Heading
          </h6>
          <p class="radial-menu__menu-content-description">
            Add a heading
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="radial-menu__menu-link"></a>
    </li>

    <li class="radial-menu__menu-item">
      <div class="radial-menu__menu-link-bg"></div>
      <div class="radial-menu__menu-icon">
        <span class="oi" data-glyph="double-quote-serif-right" title="Blockquote" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      </div>
      <div class="radial-menu__menu-content">
        <div class="radial-menu__menu-content-wrapper">
          <h6 class="radial-menu__menu-content-title">
            Blockquote
          </h6>
          <p class="radial-menu__menu-content-description">
            Add a blockquote
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="radial-menu__menu-link"></a>
    </li>

    <li class="radial-menu__menu-item">
      <div class="radial-menu__menu-link-bg"></div>
      <div class="radial-menu__menu-icon">
        <span class="oi" data-glyph="link-intact" title="Hyperlink" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      </div>
      <div class="radial-menu__menu-content">
        <div class="radial-menu__menu-content-wrapper">
          <h6 class="radial-menu__menu-content-title">
            Hyperlink
          </h6>
          <p class="radial-menu__menu-content-description">
            Add a link to something
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="radial-menu__menu-link"></a>
    </li>

    <li class="radial-menu__menu-item">
      <div class="radial-menu__menu-link-bg"></div>
      <div class="radial-menu__menu-icon">
        <span class="oi" data-glyph="image" title="Image" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      </div>
      <div class="radial-menu__menu-content">
        <div class="radial-menu__menu-content-wrapper">
          <h6 class="radial-menu__menu-content-title">
            Image
          </h6>
          <p class="radial-menu__menu-content-description">
            Add an image
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="radial-menu__menu-link"></a>
    </li>

    <li class="radial-menu__menu-item" style="display: none;">
      <div class="radial-menu__menu-link-bg"></div>
      <div class="radial-menu__menu-icon">
        <span class="oi" data-glyph="paperclip" title="Attach File" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      </div>
      <div class="radial-menu__menu-content">
        <div class="radial-menu__menu-content-wrapper">
          <h6 class="radial-menu__menu-content-title">
            Attach File
          </h6>
          <p class="radial-menu__menu-content-description">
            Attach a file
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="radial-menu__menu-link"></a>
    </li>

    <li class="radial-menu__menu-item" style="display: none;">
      <div class="radial-menu__menu-link-bg"></div>
      <div class="radial-menu__menu-icon">
        <span class="oi" data-glyph="code" title="Code" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      </div>
      <div class="radial-menu__menu-content">
        <div class="radial-menu__menu-content-wrapper">
          <h6 class="radial-menu__menu-content-title">
            Code
          </h6>
          <p class="radial-menu__menu-content-description">
            Add some HTML
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="radial-menu__menu-link"></a>
    </li>

    <li class="radial-menu__menu-item" style="display: none;">
      <div class="radial-menu__menu-link-bg"></div>
      <div class="radial-menu__menu-icon">
        <span class="oi" data-glyph="eyedropper" title="Font Color" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      </div>
      <div class="radial-menu__menu-content">
        <div class="radial-menu__menu-content-wrapper">
          <h6 class="radial-menu__menu-content-title">
            Font Color
          </h6>
          <p class="radial-menu__menu-content-description">
            Set font color
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="radial-menu__menu-link"></a>
    </li>

    <li class="radial-menu__menu-item" style="display: none;">
      <div class="radial-menu__menu-link-bg"></div>
      <div class="radial-menu__menu-icon">
        <span class="oi" data-glyph="droplet" title="Highlight Color" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      </div>
      <div class="radial-menu__menu-content">
        <div class="radial-menu__menu-content-wrapper">
          <h6 class="radial-menu__menu-content-title">
            Highlight Color
          </h6>
          <p class="radial-menu__menu-content-description">
            Set font color
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="radial-menu__menu-link"></a>
    </li>

    <li class="radial-menu__menu-item" style="display: none;">
      <div class="radial-menu__menu-link-bg"></div>
      <div class="radial-menu__menu-icon">
        <span class="oi" data-glyph="ellipses" title="More" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      </div>
      <div class="radial-menu__menu-content">
        <div class="radial-menu__menu-content-wrapper">
          <h6 class="radial-menu__menu-content-title">
            More
          </h6>
          <p class="radial-menu__menu-content-description">
            Add more things
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="radial-menu__menu-link"></a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <div class="radial-menu__label">
    Menu
  </div>
</div>

<div class="menu-items-select">
  <label class="menu-items-select__label" for="menu-items-to-show">Menu items</label>
  <select class="menu-items-select__select" name="menu-items-to-show" id="menu-items-to-show">
    <option value="3">Three</option>
    <option value="4">Four</option>
    <option value="5">Five</option>
    <option value="6">Six</option>
    <option value="7">Seven</option>
    <option value="8">Eight</option>
    <option value="9">Nine</option>
    <option value="10" selected>Ten</option>
    <option value="11">Eleven</option>
    <option value="12">Twelve</option>
    <option value="13">Thirteen</option>
    <option value="14">Fourteen</option>
    <option value="15">Fifteen</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div class="right-click-prompt">
  <p class="right-click-prompt__label">
    Right click and drag
  </p>
</div>   

CSS



       //
//  BASIC STYLES
//–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––

*, *:before, *:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  // font-family: 'Crete Round', sans-serif;
  // font-family: 'Volkhov', sans-serif;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}


//
//  COLOR
//–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––

$white: #fff;
$black: #000;

$color-primary: #d4dde5;
$color-primary-lighter: lighten($color-primary, 2%);
$color-primary-lightest: lighten($color-primary, 6%);
$color-primary-darker: darken($color-primary, 2%);
$color-primary-darkest: darken($color-primary, 6%);

$color-secondary: #6d9bc5;
$color-secondary-lighter: lighten($color-secondary, 2%);
$color-secondary-lightest: lighten($color-secondary, 6%);
$color-secondary-darker: darken($color-secondary, 2%);
$color-secondary-darkest: darken($color-secondary, 6%);


//
//  MENU
//–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––

$radial-menu-dimensions: 300px;

$radial-menu-bg: $color-primary-darkest;
// $radial-menu-bg: transparent;
$radial-menu-border-width: 0;
$radial-menu-border-color: transparent;

$radial-menu-item-hovered-bg: $color-secondary;
$radial-menu-item-hovered-border-width: 0;
// $radial-menu-item-hovered-border-color: darken($color-secondary-darkest, 6%);
$radial-menu-item-hovered-border-color: transparent;


//
//  LABEL
//–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––

$radial-menu-label-dimensions: 80px;

$radial-menu-label-font-size: 12px;
$radial-menu-label-font-weight: bold;

$radial-menu-label-bg: $color-primary-lightest;
$radial-menu-label-border-width: 3px;
$radial-menu-label-border-color: $color-primary-darker;
$radial-menu-label-font-color: $color-primary-darkest;


//
//  MENU CONTENT
//–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––

$radial-menu-content-dimensions: 80px;

$radial-menu-content-bg: $color-primary-lightest;
$radial-menu-content-border-width: 3px;
$radial-menu-content-border-color: $color-primary-darker;

$radial-menu-content-bg-hover: $color-secondary-darkest;
$radial-menu-content-border-color-hover: $color-secondary-darkest;

$radial-menu-content-title-font-size: .7em;
$radial-menu-content-title-font-weight: bold;
$radial-menu-content-title-font-color: $white;

$radial-menu-content-description-font-size: .4em;
$radial-menu-content-description-font-weight: normal;
$radial-menu-content-description-font-color: rgba($white, .5);


//
//  MENU ICON
//–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––

$radial-menu-icon-default-transform: translateY(-50%) translateX(-50%);
$radial-menu-icon-dimensions: 25px;
$radial-menu-icon-dimensions-hover: 50px;
$radial-menu-icon-icon-size: 16px;
$radial-menu-icon-icon-size-hover: 21px;

// $radial-menu-icon-bg: darken($color-primary-darkest, 8%);
// $radial-menu-icon-bg-hover: darken($color-primary-darkest, 4%);
// $radial-menu-icon-bg-hover: $white;
// $radial-menu-icon-bg-not-hovered: lighten($radial-menu-icon-bg, 4%);
$radial-menu-icon-bg: transparent;
$radial-menu-icon-bg-hover: transparent;
$radial-menu-icon-bg-hover: transparent;
$radial-menu-icon-bg-not-hovered: transparent;

$radial-menu-icon-color: darken($color-primary-darkest, 16%);
$radial-menu-icon-color-hover: $white;
$radial-menu-icon-color-not-hovered: darken($color-primary-darkest, 8%);


//
//  MENU ITEM
//–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––

$radial-menu-item-default-transform: translateY(-50%);
$radial-menu-item-trapezoid-transform: perspective(200px) rotateY(-77.5deg) scaleX(1.25);

$radial-menu-item-bg: $color-primary-lighter;
// $radial-menu-item-bg-hover: $color-primary-lightest;
$radial-menu-item-bg-hover: $color-secondary;

$radial-menu-item-border-width: 1px;
$radial-menu-item-border-color: $color-primary;
$radial-menu-item-border-color-hover: $color-secondary;

$radial-menu-inset-bg: $color-primary-darkest;
// $radial-menu-inset-bg-hover: darken($color-primary-darkest, 4%);
$radial-menu-inset-bg-hover: $color-secondary;


//
//  RADIAL MENU
//–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––

.radial-menu {
  background: $radial-menu-bg;
  border: $radial-menu-border-width solid $radial-menu-border-color;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0 25px 50px rgba($black, .05);
  height: $radial-menu-dimensions;
  left: 50%;
  opacity: 1;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(1);
  transition: 
    opacity .1s ease,
    background .1s ease;
  width: $radial-menu-dimensions;

  &.is-hidden {
    animation-name: scale-down;
    animation-duration: .2s;
    animation-delay: 0;
    animation-iteration-count: 1;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards; /* this prevents the animation from restarting! */
    animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(.25, .25, .25, 1.25);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(0) !important;
    opacity: 0;
  }

  &.is-active {
    animation-name: scale-up;
    animation-duration: .2s;
    animation-delay: 0;
    animation-iteration-count: 1;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards; /* this prevents the animation from restarting! */
    animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(.25, .25, .25, 1.25);
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(1);
  }

  &.item-is-hovered {
    background-color: $radial-menu-item-hovered-bg;
    border-color: $radial-menu-item-hovered-border-color;
    border-width: $radial-menu-item-hovered-border-width;
  }
}


@keyframes scale-up {
  0% {
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(-50%, -50%) scale(1);
  }
}

@keyframes scale-down {
  0% {
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(1);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(-50%, -50%) scale(0);
  }
}


//
//  LABEL
//–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––

.radial-menu__label {
  background-color: $radial-menu-label-bg;
  border: $radial-menu-label-border-width solid $radial-menu-label-border-color;
  border-radius: 50%;
  // box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(#fff, .2);
  color: $radial-menu-label-font-color;
  cursor: default;
  font-size: $radial-menu-label-font-size;
  font-weight: $radial-menu-label-font-weight;
  height: $radial-menu-label-dimensions;
  left: 50%;
  letter-spacing: .1em;
  line-height: $radial-menu-label-dimensions - ($radial-menu-label-border-width * 2);
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: $radial-menu-label-dimensions;
  z-index: 4;
}

.radial-menu {
  &.item-is-hovered {
    .radial-menu__label {
      // transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(1.1);
    }
  }
}



//
//  MENU CONTENT
//–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––

.radial-menu__menu-content {
  background-color: $radial-menu-content-bg;
  border: $radial-menu-content-border-width solid $radial-menu-content-border-color;
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: $radial-menu-content-dimensions;
  left: 50%;
  // opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  // transition: all .1s ease;
  width: $radial-menu-content-dimensions;
  z-index: 1;
}

// Hover.
.radial-menu__menu-item {
  &.hovered {
    .radial-menu__menu-content {
      background-color: $radial-menu-content-bg-hover;
      border-color: $radial-menu-content-border-color-hover;
      // opacity: 1;
      transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
      z-index: 4;
    }
  }
}

.radial-menu__menu-content-wrapper {
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  width: 100%;
}

.radial-menu__menu-content-title {
  color: $radial-menu-content-title-font-color;
  font-size: $radial-menu-content-title-font-size;
  font-weight: $radial-menu-content-title-font-weight;
  // letter-spacing: .05em;
  // margin-bottom: 4px;
  line-height: 1.3;
  // text-transform: uppercase;
}

.radial-menu__menu-content-description {
  color: $radial-menu-content-description-font-color;
  display: none;
  font-size: $radial-menu-content-description-font-size;
  font-weight: $radial-menu-content-description-font-weight;
  letter-spacing: .1em;
  line-height: 1.3;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}


//
//  MENU ICON
//–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––

.radial-menu__menu-icon {
  background-color: $radial-menu-icon-bg;
  // border-radius: 50%;
  // display: none; // OFF
  height: $radial-menu-icon-dimensions;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  top: 0;
  transform: $radial-menu-icon-default-transform;
  width: $radial-menu-icon-dimensions;
  z-index: 2;

  .oi {
    color: $radial-menu-icon-color;
    font-size: $radial-menu-icon-icon-size;
    line-height: $radial-menu-icon-dimensions;
    transition: 
      font-size .3s cubic-bezier(.25, .25, .25, 1.5),
      color .1s ease;
  }
}

// Not hovered.
.radial-menu {
  &.item-is-hovered {
    .radial-menu__menu-icon {
      background-color: $radial-menu-icon-bg-not-hovered;

      .oi {
        color: $radial-menu-icon-color-not-hovered;
      }
    }
  }
}

// Hovered.
.radial-menu {
  &.item-is-hovered {
    .radial-menu__menu-item {
      &.hovered {
        .radial-menu__menu-icon {
          background-color: $radial-menu-icon-bg-hover;
          height: $radial-menu-icon-dimensions-hover;
          width: $radial-menu-icon-dimensions-hover;

          .oi {
            color: $radial-menu-icon-color-hover;
            font-size: $radial-menu-icon-icon-size-hover;
            line-height: $radial-menu-icon-dimensions-hover;
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}


//
//  MENU LIST
//–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––

.radial-menu__menu-list {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}


//
//  MENU ITEM
//–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––

.radial-menu__menu-item {
  display: block;
  left: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  z-index: 1;

  &.hovered {
    z-index: 10;
  }
}


//
//  MENU LINK
//–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––

.radial-menu__menu-link,
.radial-menu__menu-link-bg {
  height: 22px;
  padding: 5px 20px;
  position: absolute;
  transform: $radial-menu-item-default-transform $radial-menu-item-trapezoid-transform;
  transform-origin: 0;
  transform-style: preserve-3d; 
  width: 125px;
}

.radial-menu__menu-link {
  border-bottom: $radial-menu-item-border-width solid transparent;
  border-top: $radial-menu-item-border-width solid transparent;
  display: block;
  z-index: 3;
}


//
//  MENU LINK BG
//–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––

.radial-menu__menu-link-bg {
  background-color: $radial-menu-item-bg;
  border-bottom: $radial-menu-item-border-width solid $radial-menu-item-border-color;
  border-top: $radial-menu-item-border-width solid $radial-menu-item-border-color;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  transition: background .1s ease;
  z-index: 1;

  &:after {
    background: $radial-menu-inset-bg;
    content: '';
    display: none;
    // height: 100%;
    height: 106%;
    right: -1px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    transition: all .1s ease;
    transform: translateY(-3%);
    width: 2px;
  }
}

// Hover.
.radial-menu__menu-item {
  &.hovered {
    .radial-menu__menu-link-bg {
      background-color: $radial-menu-item-bg-hover;
      // border-color: $radial-menu-item-border-color-hover;
      // border-width: 0;
      border: 0;

      &:after {
        background: $radial-menu-inset-bg-hover;
        height: 106%;
        transform: translateY(-3%);
        width: 0;
      }
    }
  }
}


//
//  MENU ITEM SELECT
//–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––

.menu-items-select {
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 40px;
  position: absolute;
  // text-align: center;
}

.menu-items-select__label {
  color: $color-primary-darkest;
  display: block;
  font-size: .7em;
  font-weight: bold;
  letter-spacing: .05em;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.menu-items-select__select {
  appearance: none;
  background-color: $color-primary-lightest;

  // Black dropdown arrow.
  background-image:url('data:image/png;base64,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');

  background-position: 97.5% 50%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  border: 2px solid $color-primary;
  border-radius: 0;
  display: block;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: .9em;
  font-weight: bold;
  height: 40px;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  width: 100px;
}


//
//  MENU ITEM SELECT
//–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––

.right-click-prompt {
  bottom: 0;
  color: $color-primary-darkest;
  font-size: .7em;
  font-weight: bold;
  left: 50%;
  letter-spacing: .05em;
  padding: 40px;
  position: absolute;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}

@media (max-height: 430px) {
  .right-click-prompt {
    left: 0;
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
}
```